# Dynamic object creation from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to generate a dynamic object and assign value into it. Following is the code

```
var chunk = "INTERNATIONALISATION#LANGUAGE#DICTIONARY#EN";
var c = chunk.split('#');
var a = {};
```

So the output should be like this

```
a["INTERNATIONALISATION"]["LANGUAGE"]["DICTIONARY"]["EN"] = 10;
```

Tried looping through array but nothing works for now.Please advise.

Comment: What does not work exactly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
var chunk = "INTERNATIONALISATION#LANGUAGE#DICTIONARY#EN";
var c = chunk.split('#');
var a = {};
var lastKey = c.pop();
c.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] = obj[key] || {}, a)[lastKey] = 10;
```

To make it more convenient you can put it in a function:

```
const dynamicAssign = (object, stringPath, value) => {
    const path = stringPath.split('#');
    const lastKey = path.pop();
    const target = path.reduce((obj, key) => obj[key] = obj[key] || {}, object);
    target[lastKey] = value;
};

const a = {};
dynamicAssign(a, "INTERNATIONALISATION#LANGUAGE#DICTIONARY#EN", 10);
```

Comment: 1+ short and perfect!

Comment: Why would you use a dynamic "object generator" if you then assign a value to one of its properties by hand? O.o

Comment: I cannot assign value directly as a["INTERNATIONALISATION"]["LANGUAGE"]["DICTIONARY"]["EN"] = 10.

Comment: @Andreas, my answer was answering what the OP asked for.. I couldn't assume that this wasn't what he really wanted :)